# How can I add a device to development portal in Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, code-signing, xcode6, provisioning-profile

I see that Xcode6 has removed the "Devices" tab from the organizer and moved it to a separate "Devices" tab in Window > Devices.

I do not see an option for "Add device to Member Center" from the Devices screen or the Devices > Provisioning Profiles screen.

How can I add a device to Member Center and thus get the correct provisioning profiles installed in Xcode 6?

Comment: I can't find this option either and am looking for an answer !

Comment: Xcode 6 just fixes the issue for you, it seems, when you attempt to run your app on a device without a provisioning profile.  Simply press *Fix Issue* and it does just that.

Comment: I don't have anything like Fix Issue button?

Comment: When you run the app on a device which has not been registered, Xcode should offer to fix the issue.

Comment: @trojanfoe I certainly don't see that option. Mine says "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found." and only gives me the option of saying "OK"

Comment: Xcode offers me to fix it on some occasions, but sometimes, it just says that no valid profile was found, without offering a fix. I really wonder why they broke something working without properly testing the new one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your build settings, set your provisioning profile to automatic. 
Code signing identity to automatic as well.

In some cases the xCode tries to fix both the main target and the "tests" target, but fails to properly sign the tests target. In such case, for demos downloaded from the internet, I just delete the tests target.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to provision a device using the organizer or device menu without a project? I just want to add a device to my team provisioning profile.

Comment: I think you can add the device's UDID to your provisioning profile through developer.apple.com>iOs dev center> certificates

Comment: Whatever happened to the old "Use for development" button?

Comment: Apple XCode updates are really making life super awesome by removing important stuff and making simple things too complicated.

Answer (score 3):

@SeniorShizzle I think that the reason that it's showing like that for you is because your phone is running on a version lesser than the Deployment Target set in your app (Xcode -> YourAppName -> General).

Sorry that I couldn't reply as a comment btw. I'm not allowed to do that yet.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. Delete 'iOS Team provisioning profile:*' in iPhone configuration utility.

and try to run app then you could see fix issue.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason you might have trouble adding a new device is that you have reached your limit (100) on the number of devices you are allowed to register.

Answer (score 0):

My first time using XCode and apparently starting from version 6 they moved the creation of provisioning profile the developer.apple.com website. There you can register your device using the UUID you can find in XCode > Window > Devices for your phone. Then create an App ID and then a provisioning profile which you can then download from the website. Double clicking the downloaded file should add it to XCode > Windows > Devices > Show Provision Profiles.